# Search for multiple patterns which included double quotes in single file and comment above and below two lines

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a very large file where I need to search for 40 patterns.
If pattern got matched in the file then need to comment before 2 lines and after 2 lines.
Patterns will be like as shown below:

```
1.create_rev -name "2x_8_PLL"
2.create_generated_rev -name "76_L"
3.create_rev -name "PCS_T0"
4.create_generated_rev -name "x544_P"
```

If I need to search for single pattern then I can execute below gvim command to accomplish the task.

```
:g/create_rev -name "2x_8_PLL"/-2,+2s/^/#
```

But the search patterns are more in number 40 plus. How to search/grep for 40+ patterns such that my expected output as shown below:

```
#pp
#oo
create_rev -name "2x_8_PLL"
#aa
#bb
hh
#ii
#jj
create_generated_rev -name "76_L"
#cc
#dd
create_rev -name "PCS_T0"
#ee
#ff
gg
```

Comment: You could use a pipe (`\|`) to separate each pattern: `:g/create_rev -name "2x_8_PLL"\|create_generated_rev -name "76_L"/-2,+2s/^/#`. Of course, in the example you posted, you can also just do `:g/create/-2,+2s/^/#` so maybe you can come up with one or more patterns that together capture the 40 you want (maybe something like `:g/create_.* -name ".*"/-2,+2s/^/#`)

Comment: @mattb, Yes I can use pipe line and do the above thing in gvim .. but I need to accomplish that in either sed or grep or bash by using array. I cannot use .* pattern it in my case.

Comment: `awk` below is what I would use. If you really need `sed` the look for `sed -f script.sed input > output` type solutions. See the [sed tutorial](https://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-16) for some ideas. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that when you say "pattern" what you really want is full-line string matching then using any awk in any shell on every Unix box and handling cases of overlapping ranges by commenting them as presumably required and not double-commenting them as could happen with other solutions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
ARGIND==1 {
    targets[$0]
    next
}
ARGIND==2 {
    if ($0 in targets) {
        for (i=FNR-2; i<=FNR+2; i++) {
            if (i != FNR) {
                hits[i]
            }
        }
    }
    next
}
FNR in hits {
    $0 = "#" $0
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk targets file file
#pp
#oo
create_rev -name "2x_8_PLL"
#aa
#bb
hh
#ii
#jj
create_generated_rev -name "76_L"
#cc
#dd
create_rev -name "PCS_T0"
#ee
#ff
gg
```

```
$ cat targets
create_rev -name "2x_8_PLL"
create_generated_rev -name "76_L"
create_rev -name "PCS_T0"
create_generated_rev -name "x544_P"
```

The above uses GNU awk for ARGIND. If you don't have GNU awk then change `ARGIND==1` to `FILENAME==ARGV[1]` and `ARGIND==2` to `FILENAME==ARGV[2]`.

Comment: Is the "very large file" iterated twice?

Comment: @ceving yes it's iterated twice with simple, robust, extremely fast code using very little memory (for all but 40 lines all that will happen on the first iteration is a hash lookup, and the same for no more than 160 lines on the second iteration) as opposed to iterated once with some combination of more complicated, fragile, slower and more memory-intensive code.

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU grep and sed):

```
grep -A2 -B2 -nFf targets file |sed -En 's/^([0-9]+)-.*/\1s@^@#@/p' |sed -f - file
```

Use grep to ouput lines in the file matching the lines in the targets. The matches will be line numbered and contain two lines before and after the matches.

The lines output from the grep command are piped into sed and used as addresses for a sed script, which inserts a `#` at the start of each matching address.

The sed script created from the ouput of the first sed invocation (by way of the `-f` command line option and the `-` which uses stdin from the pipe) is used in the second sed invocation which edits the source file.

Another solution using sed only:

```
sed -E 's/.*/\\#\\n.*\\n&\\n.*\\n#bb/' targets |
sed -Ee ':a;N;s/\n/&/4;Ta' -f - -e 'bc;:b;s/^([^#])/#\1/mg;s/^#//m3;:c;P;D' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If `ed` is available/acceptable with some help from the shell.

The script `myscript`

```
#!/bin/sh

targets=$1
file=$2

{
ed -s "$targets" <<'EOF'
g|.|t.\
-1s|^|g/|\
s|$|/-2;+1s/^\\(#\\)\\{0,1\\}\\(.*\\)/#\\2/\\|\
+1s|.*|;+2;+1s/^\\(#\\)\\{0,1\\}\\(.*\\)/#\\2/|
$a
,p
Q
.
,p
Q
EOF
} | ed -s "$file"
```

---

```
./myscript targets file
```

- Remove the first `,p` to silence the output to `stdout`
- Change the first `Q` to `w` if *in-place* editing is needed.
- Memory issues from `ed` could occur depending on how big the `big file` is.